# Problems after porting app from XP to Win7

Tags: dll, windows-7, windows-xp

We have an application that consists of a compiled exe using a bunch of dll's for the GUI. This application has been used for years, and it works fine without major problems - so we assume there are no (major) errors in our software.

We have ported this to Win7 recently, i.e. we compile our source now on Win7 and link it to the same dll's. Now the app is not working proerly anymore - in fact the GUI will become unresponsive after some time, and only react to a few inputs.

Assuming there are no errors in our application - what could be the cause of this? Should the dll's work on XP and Win7 the same, or is there something we need to look out for/take care of?

**Update:**
Well we found a fix. Seems that some changes in our application do not work well with the GUI dll's on Win7. We could split the application so that one part needs the GUI dll's, but has no changes - so it works. The other part has the changes, but needs no GUI, and by compiling it without the dll's this part works as well. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Without providing any information, there's no way we can help with this. There are any number of things that could be going wrong. The biggest differences tend to be in permissions - many old apps used to save things in their program directory or wherever they wanted. Now you are to be saving things in user or shared app data directories. Also some Win32 API calls require administrator privileges, which tended to be given by default in XP but no longer in Win 7. The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your program runs correctly in "Compatibility Mode" : [Compatibility Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-Windows)

(In the Control Panel on Windows 7 look for "Programs and Features" and select "Run programs made for previous versions of windows"